SQL inline query insertinto
INSERT INTO ServiceID_302
 (Services)
 VALUES (
('Preliminaries'),
 ('Demolition'),
 ('DRAINAGE_AND_REFUSE_DISPOSAL'),
 ('GAS_DISTRIBUTION-COMPRESSED_AIR'),
 ('SPACE_COOLING-CHILLED_WATER'),
 ('SPACE_HEATING-LOW_PRESSURE_HOT_WATER'),
 ('VENTILATION_&_AIR_CONDITIONING'),
 ('OTHER_MECHANICAL_SERVICES'),
 ('Sprinkler'),
 ('Dayworks'),
 ('COMMERCIAL_DISCOUNT'),
 ('VARIATIONS')
 );

I am trying to insert this using inline query it throws an error :

There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.'

I have this structure where id is primary key also its a identity column
     SELECT [Id]
          ,[Services]
      FROM [CostManagement].[dbo].[ServiceID_302]


This looks like SQL Server, but the tags explicitly indicate MySQL.  Can you clarify?  And how is C# involved?

You don't need the outer braces to wrap all data rows to be inserted. Remove the outer opening and closing braces: INSERT INTO ServiceID_302 (Services) VALUES ('Preliminaries'), ..., ('VARIATIONS');

What do you mean by 'inline query'?

You're trying to insert a single row with 12 columns where one column is expected, not 12 rows with one column. Parentheses have significant meaning here.

Brackets are more than needed. Remove the ones that wraps all Values
INSERT INTO ServiceID_302
 (Services)
 VALUES 
 ('Preliminaries'),
 ('Demolition'),
 ('DRAINAGE_AND_REFUSE_DISPOSAL'),
 ('GAS_DISTRIBUTION-COMPRESSED_AIR'),
 ('SPACE_COOLING-CHILLED_WATER'),
 ('SPACE_HEATING-LOW_PRESSURE_HOT_WATER'),
 ('VENTILATION_&_AIR_CONDITIONING'),
 ('OTHER_MECHANICAL_SERVICES'),
 ('Sprinkler'),
 ('Dayworks'),
 ('COMMERCIAL_DISCOUNT'),
 ('VARIATIONS') 

